# Coloring tables without xcolor, colortbl and tabu while using listings package

Tags: tables, errors, listings, color, tabu

currently, I want to color my tables. However, presumably since I'm using the listings package, I can't apply the abovementioned packages, as they totally mess up the default table looks (lines between columns/rows are suddenly bold). Are there any possibilities to color my tables while using listings and one of these packages?

Here's a short MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,parskip,bibtotoc,liststotoc]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
 \begin{center}
 \vspace*{1mm}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|} %hier die Spaltenausrichtung, -breite, -begrenzung und -anzahl eintragen

        \hline
        XYZ & ABC \\ \hline
        XXX & YYY\\
        & Lorem\\
        & Ipsum\\
        & Dolores est\\
        \hline 
 \end{tabular} \\[2mm]
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-15pt}
 \caption{Attributes station class} \label{Table6}
 \end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

You should see the issue I'm talking about when using it.

edit: I now updated my miktex version and everything is still screwed. However, here is a link to a picture depicting the issues:

[image]

you can see that the lines between the customer type and the setting is bold. I dont want it to be bold, since most other lines aren't.

edit 2: It comes even worse: when I use the \rowcolor command the table borders get completely messed up, as some borders between columns completely disappear. Here's a pic and the respective code:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[htb!]
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|} %hier die Spaltenausrichtung, -breite, -begrenzung und -anzahl eintragen
        \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Day & Customer type & Setting 1 & Setting 2\\ \hline
        &1 &\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{25} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{35}\\
        &2 & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{6}\\
        &3 & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{2}\\ \hline
        \rowcolor{Gray}
        Night&Customer type &Setting 1&Setting 2\\ \hline
        &1 &\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{25} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{35}\\
        &2 & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{6}\\
        &3 & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{2}\\        
\hline 
 \end{tabular} \\[2mm]
 \caption{Setting of possible system settings} \label{Table4}
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: The correct name of the package is `colortbl` and not `colorbtl`!

Comment: i don't see the issue you're talking about.  what engine are you using?  what vintage of tex distro?  (i tried "unadorned" tex, pdftex "explicitly", xelatex and lualatex, all from my tl'14 installation).

Comment: I'm using pdflatex+Makeindex+Bibtex in Miktex. My miktex versions is, however, quite old (about 3 years I guess).

Comment: @Atlan Three... years...! Time to update.

Comment: You can be pretty confident that if updating to MikTeX 2.9 is screwing up things, it's the document not the distro as the culprit unless it is about engine problems such as luaotfload or some naming convention.

Comment: Please fix the examples in the question, the document that we can run does not have the issue, the error is in the second fragment that should be in the example document so that people can run it.

Comment: If I knew how to invoke the problem, I would also know how to fix it ;) However, the problem was identified by David Carlisle, so I will probably close this thread soon!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is nothing to do with listings, the lines are bold as you have specified two adjacent rules.

```
  &1 &\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{25} & \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{35}\\
```

specifies a rule at the right edge of one column and the left edge of the next so you get two rules which look like one double thickness rule.

All latex inter-column material is on the *right* edge except for the first column, which has left and right so it should be

```
&1 &\multicolumn{1}{r|}{25} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{35}\\
```

Comment: Ow - so that happens if you simply copy code. Those were solutions for aligning data in tables that were written by someone else. I didn't know that they implied some further options. I'll change the code asap and I will let you know of the outcome. In any case, I'll probably accept your answer :)

Comment: You were totally right, the multicoloumns were the problem :)